# iframe send to back in internet explorer

Tags: html, angularjs

In my application i display the pdf using iframe in project. it's display on page in front, i need to show back that pdf. this pdf is hide some menu.

html code:

```
<iframe ng-class="{'exapndCheckbox':!docList.sectionFilter,'newClass':docList.sectionFilter}"
        name="iframe" class="" style="width: 100%;display: block;"
        data-ng-src="{{docList.viewDocument.url}}" id="iframe">
    Working...
</iframe>
```

This code is display the pdf in iframe on my application, here i tried the "&wmode=opaque" this but it throws parse error. i need help to fix this problem.
for you reference the problem is [image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h17m.png)
Here the yellow line is my menu and the green is frame pdf file.

Comment: have you tried using CSS z-index?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with z-index but not working.my Iframe included of PDF document so only that z-index property does't working.

Comment: In order for `z-index` to work you also need to set the element (in this case iframe) to `position: relative` - but as you say it's a PDF, it might not work in IE. What IE version do you try to support?